# Виртуальная клавиатура

Tags: веб-программирование

Google сделал виртуальную клавиатуру. На каких языках программирования она сделана
и как называется способ перемещение объекта с помощью мышки в окне браузера, который применили при создании виртуальной клавиатуры (google.com)?

Comment: подозреваю javascript :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это JavaScript: [Google Virtual Keyboard Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/language/virtualkeyboard/v1/getting_started.html). Перемещать элемент можно по разному в зависимости от задачи: либо меняя координаты div'а в соответствии с движениями мыши, либо используя Drag'Drop.

Comment: Йода спасибо